# Ambient Data Framework Throws 500 Status Code

Tags: dxa, web8.5, ambient-data-framework

I'm working on a project using SDL Web Cloud (8.1) and DXA 1.7. I'm encountering an error with Ambient Data Framework. I enter a URL such as `.../example-page/?test`

Instead of rendering the page as is, it renders `{"error":"InternalServerError"}`.

Looking at the `cd_client.log`, I found:

> ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart] - Problem
>   EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key
>       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
>       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue, value, Boolean add)
>       at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.SetWebRequestClaims(HttpRequest
>   request, IClaimStore claimStore)
>       at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart(HttpApplication
>   application, HttpContext context, IClaimStore claimStore, ISet`1
>   templateReadOnlyClaims, ISet`1 templateImmutableClaims, ISet`1
>   templateSessionScopeClaims, Boolean dispatchOdataRequest)
>
> ERROR: [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart] - Setting
>   status code:500

What I've tried:

- Disable ADF from web.config - page renders as expected
- Step through via PageController to identify where ADF is referenced or error is thrown - no luck
- Check site log - no error
- Reviewed `cd_ambient_conf.xml` to see if there's any configuration to avoid this - no luck
- Reviewed ADF documentation

Is there anything I can do (i.e. perhaps using a RequestValidator) to avoid returning this error? There will be instances when query string value will be empty.

Comment: The problem seems to be that one of the claims has 'null' for a URI, which is not allowed (nor expected, apparently). 

You should check the name/key of anything in the request (including cookies and headers) to see if you can figure out the culprit -- and also check the cartridges that you have installed as maybe one of them is adding the claim without a claim URI.

Comment: I guess the assumption in the ADF is that query string parameters are in format `key=value`, whereas your query string parameter only has a key (`test`)

Comment: Enable the TRACE logs on both dxa web app and content service to see your claims values what is get forwarded, could be some firewall trip out some headers values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working in an SDL Cloud implementation which made it difficult to troubleshoot this issue. I reached out to SDL and they've provided a hotfix (CD_8.5.0.6337) which worked.